# Sending auditd records to my audispd plugin

Tags: linux, audit, auditd

After setting `auditctl`'s rules, I want to send those matched records to my Python script for further analysis.

These are the involved files:

- `auditd` records:

  ```
  type=PATH msg=audit(1451011319.268:533): ...
  type=CWD msg=audit(1451011319.268:533):  cwd=”/home/root”
  type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1451011319.268.230:533): ... key=(null)
  ```
- `/etc/audisp/audispd.conf` is, as follows,

  ```
  q_depth = 80
  overflow_action = ignore
  priority_boost = 4
  max_restarts = 10
  name_format = HOSTNAME
  #name = mydomain
  ```
- The `audispd` plugin configuration file in `/etc/audisp/plugin.d/`,

  ```
  active = yes
  direction = out
  path = /usr/bin/python
  type = always
  # two args, one is my Python script, the other is the log file
  args = /var/t/h.py /var/log/audit.log
  format = string
  ```
- My h.py is, as follows,

  ```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

  import sys

  print sys.argv[1]
  ...
  ```

However, my Python script can't get any records from `auditd`.

I don't know where is wrong, please give me a hand!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `audispd` is writing audit events into its plugins stdin.

*(Links to the source below are relative from https://github.com/packetstash/auditd/tree/ba912fa614a7e73160a4eba338e55890d6e8f62f.  That's my first post on Server Fault, and I can't include more than two links).*

In particular:

- it creates a pair of sockets at `audisp/audispd.c#L484`;
- then forks, sets child's stdin to one end of socket pair: `audisp/audispd.c#L500`;
- and the writes events into another end: `audisp/audispd.c#L533`.

Your script will inherit open file descriptors from `audispd`, including stdout (fd #1), which would be reopened to `/dev/null`.  So `print` in the script would likely have no effect, you'll have to write to some file.

Try something like:

```python
import sys

with open('/tmp/my_audit.log', 'w') as log_file:
  for event_message in sys.stdin:
    log_file.write('%s\n' % event_message)
```

You may also want to use `bindings/python/auparse_python.c` module to parse the event messages.